# PyAutoGui - After clicking on a specific spot, it clicks on an undefined location

Tags: python, pyautogui

Hi i'm so sorry about the way I phrased the title. I think that's the best I can explain e_e.

So instead of explaining, here's a GIF to show u what's my issue. 
Note: I've only programmed clicks in the middle of the items

[image]

Here's the code that triggers the clicking:

`INVEN` is a list that contains 56 individual values. But the way I programmed it, is to have values in pairs of 2. Meaning, `INVEN[0] = X Coords` and `INVEN[1] = Y Coords`

```
for i in range(len(INVEN) - 1):
   keyboard.press(Key.shift)
   Click("clear_inven", (INVEN[i], INVEN[i + 1]))
   keyboard.release(Key.shift)
```

Here's the `Click` code:

```
def Click(pos, xy):
   i = 0
   while i <= 3:
       if pos.upper() == "CUT_TREE":
           pyautogui.click(xy[0], xy[1])
       elif pos.upper() == "COMPASS":
           pyautogui.click(xy[0], xy[1])
       elif pos.upper() == "CLEAR_INVEN":
           pyautogui.click(xy[0], xy[1])
       i += 1
```

Thank u so much for reading! I appreciate any help at all :)

Comment: Do you have a sample of what is `INVEN`? Because when you say `INVEN[0] = X Coords` and `INVEN[1] = Y Coords` it conflicts with "`INVEN` is a list that contains 28 individual values".  Did you mean in each of the 28 `INVEN` it's a pair of `(x, y)` values?  If so `(INVEN[i], INVEN[i + 1])` is the culprit

Comment: @Idlehands Hi! Sorry. I meant 56 items! Here's how it looks like `[674, 362, 716, 362, 758, 362, 800, 362, 674, 398, 716, 398, 758, 398, 800, 398, 674, 434, 716, 434, 758, 434, 800, 434, 674, 470, 716, 470, 758, 470, 800, 470, 674, 506, 716, 506, 758, 506, 800, 506, 674, 542, 716, 542, 758, 542, 800, 542, 674, 578, 716, 578, 758, 578, 800, 578]`...... Pos 0 = X, Pos 1 = Y, Pos 2 = X, Pos 3 = Y.. etc etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here: `(INVEN[i], INVEN[i + 1])`, your `INVEN` is not incrementing properly:

```
INVEN = [674, 362, 716, 362, 758, 362, ...]

# iteration i = 0
INVEN[0] = 674 # x coord
INVEN[1] = 362 # y coord

# iteration i = 1
INVEN[1] = 362 # y coord
INVEN[2] = 716 # x coord
```

You can see how this quickly goes out of hand.

Instead you want to do this:

```
for i in range(0, len(INVEN), 2):
   keyboard.press(Key.shift)
   Click("clear_inven", (INVEN[i], INVEN[i + 1]))
   keyboard.release(Key.shift)
```

So that `i` is incremented by 2 each time `(step=2)`.

**However** it is rarely suggested to do `range(len(INVEN))` as you can easily just loop through the objects without the range:

```
for pair in zip(INVEN[::2], INVEN[1::2]):
    Click('something', pair)
```

Also it's probably better if you have your `x, y` set up in tuples:

```
[(674, 362), (716, 362), (758, 362), ...]
```

So that it's easier to recall them in pair:

```
for pair in INVEN:
    Click('something', pair)
```

As a side note, you might also want to use `for` loop instead of `while` in your `Click()` function:

```
def Click(pos, xy):
   for i in range(3):
       if pos.upper() == "CUT_TREE":
           pyautogui.click(xy[0], xy[1])
       elif pos.upper() == "COMPASS":
           pyautogui.click(xy[0], xy[1])
       elif pos.upper() == "CLEAR_INVEN":
           pyautogui.click(xy[0], xy[1])
```

Although I'm not sure why you would want to loop through the same input three times...

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The code snippet you gave me doesn't seem to be solving my issue. As for the suggestion you gave me, Is there a way to convert my list into a list full of tuples as the one u mentioned?

Comment: To convert the tuples you can do this: `list(zip(INVEN[::2], INVEN[1::2]))`

Comment: Try the `zip` method and see if it resolves your issue.  But I think there's some awkwardness in `Click()` function as well, though without further details it's hard to gauge.

Comment: Thanks for all ur helpful tips! I went with the method of converting my list into tuples of (x, y)! It works flawlessly